# How to make a small box appear over parts of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image that has multiple sections using an image map, I'd like it so when a user hovers their mouse over the image, a small box appears over that specified part of the image with a button that says "Click here to download PDF"

```
<img style=" display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-bottom: 30px" 
                        src="myimage.png" alt="" width="983" height="634" usemap="#imageMap"/>
                        <map name="imageMap">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="20,400,182,200" href="" style="outline: none">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="480,400,200,200" href="mypdf.pdf" style="outline: none" download>
                            <area shape="rect" coords="650,400,500,220" href="#image4" style="outline: none">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="665,420,900,280" href="#image5" style="outline: none">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="765,425,900,575" href="#image6" style="outline: none">
                            <area shape="rect" coords="250,425,500,575" href="#image7" style="outline: none">
                        </map>
```

As of right now I can click the area and have it download, But I'd like for a small box to appear over that part of the image with the option to download.

Comment: Why not just use the native `title` attr? It's part of [global attributes list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)

Comment: because the popup i need would have both text and a button inside of it.

Comment: fair enough. what have you tried? what is the problem you've run into?